# How expensive is StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase in C# string equality comparison?

Tags: c#, equality, string-comparison

I have multiple instances in code where we have done StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase for equality comparison of two strings.
Given,
- In our code strings are based on single culture (en)
- There would 'rarely' be a case of two strings just varying in case (atleast for most of the values).

I am looking for some opinion on how expensive (performance) is StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase than the default stringOne.Equals(stringtwo). If the difference is considerable I would do one full iteration of code and remove at all the places where it does not make sense (for instance, comparing RecordId like this).

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What do you need an *opinion* for? Try running it, get out a stopwatch, and then you'll have *facts*. Facts are way more useful than opinions.

Comment: @Eric Gosh darnnit we need more [truthiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) not more facts ;)

Comment: @EricLippert: Agree, facts are more useful. But most often we can just do with opinions (or truthiness, as suggested by @shuggycoUK), because of the time and resource constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [String.Equals Performance Comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2007/06/29/string-equals-performance-comparison.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks. Just the comparison i was looking for.